# starting a jar from batch file blocks the batch file

Tags: batch-file, bufferedreader, processbuilder

I created a batch file to start a jar, and I am running this from process Builder. when the start command is triggered control never comes back and BufferReader goes into an infinite loop. Appreciate any help to unblock this.

running this code on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

*Java code*

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("startabx6.bat",abx);
 pb.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
 Process process = pb.start();
 String line;
 BufferedReader reader  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while (((line = reader.readLine())!=null )) {
            log.info(line);
        }
        reader.close();
```

*Batch file*

```
@ECHO OFF
echo %1
set build=%1
echo %build%
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8080') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %%P /F
echo "launching abx jar"
start java -jar -DServer.port=8080 libs\ABJars\%build%
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! The solution that worked for me was to use the `StreamGobbler` class, which enables reading logs in a different thread.